# H2 database performance strangeness --- or how to efficiently `count(*)`

Tags: database, h2

The setup could not be simpler:

- H2 version 1.3.176
- One table, 10 columns of which two are a bit lengthy with 300 and 3500 characters a typical value length
- Simple query: `select count(*) from requestrepository where request_type = 'ADD'`
- Index is on the queried column.
- Queried column is just varchar(20) (i.e. not one of the longer ones)
- Queried column contains just two different values, with one appearing 200k times and the other appearing 12 million times.
- DB runs off an SSD, current server hardware, current Java 8 (varied a bit but no change in result)

What I do: (0) run `analyze`, (1) delete one row by a key field, (2) insert one row for the key just deleted, (3) run the query cited above, count to 10 and repeat.

What I see: The query cited above takes between 3 and 5 seconds each time and `explain analyze` says:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM PUBLIC.REQUESTREPOSITORY
    /* PUBLIC.IX_REQUESTS: REQUEST_TYPE = 'ADD' */
    /* scanCount: 12098748 */
WHERE REQUEST_TYPE = 'ADD'
/*
REQUESTREPOSITORY.IX_REQUESTS read: 126700
*/
```

I tried the same DB on different machines, hardware/linux/ssd, VM/Windows/netapp, but the tendency is always the same: the `count(*)` takes too(?) long.

And this is what I am not sure about. Is it to be expected that this takes long? I would have thought that at least for the second round, caches are filled and this should be much faster, but the `explain analyze` always lists 126700 reads.

Any hints about H2 parameters or settings how this may be improve are appreciated.

EDIT (not sure if this should rather go as an answer)
Meanwhile we tried a wide range of things, including mvstore, 1.4.x, parallel threads, computers with different disks, Linux, Windows. The situation is always the same. Take over 10 or 12 million rows, a varchar column with three status values, something like PROCESSING, ADD, DELETE, an index on the column and one status grossly overrepresented: Then something like `count(*) where colname='ADD'` takes between 1 and many seconds after each update of the table.

To prevent this from creating a problem, we finally fixed our own code, which  did three `count(*)`, one for each status, instead of one with a `group by` and was run every 5 seconds instead of just on demand. Certainly not the greatest design we had.

The only excuse I have is that it I am still surprised that a `count(*)` takes that long in such a setup. My hunch is that the count must be computed on the index by really counting after an update, whereas I expected that the count can be just read off the data structure somewhere. (No critique, I for myself would certainly not be able to implement a DB.)

Comment: Did you try using the latest version of H2 (with the MVStore format)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about H2, but have you tried `COUNT(request_type)` instead of `COUNT(*)`?

SQL standard's `COUNT(*)` tends to take long time to compute, as it requires a full table scan to filter out rows that consist of `NULL` values only.

Using `COUNT()` on a single indexed column can speed things up. This way no table row need to be read, as the index is sufficient to decide whether the column's value is NULL.